# Finding large changes in consecutive numbers in database

Tags: sql-server, database, validation

I have a sql server DB which contains large amount of daily share prices of companies. My goal is to automatize data validation which goes through daily price changes of each company and notices large changes (> +/-50 % for example) to find errors/splits. DB structure is following:

```
Ticker  Date        Price
AMEAS   2010-01-03  11,20
AMEAS   2010-01-02  11,00
AMEAS   2010-01-01  10,00
KNEVB   2010-01-03  5,00
KNEVB   2010-01-02  3,50
KNEVB   2010-01-01  3,50
```

So I want the script to go through each ticker (AMEAS, KNEVB in this case) and check the ratio between each consecutive days (ameas 2010-01-02 and ameas 2010-01-01: 11.00 / 10.00 etc..), if ratio is more than 1.5 or less than 0.5 then make a note.

Question: Is this kind of checks which need calculations even possible to do in database (check constraints? queries? anything else? If so, can you point me to right direction where I could start figuring this out. If no, do you have any suggestions where to do this?

Thank you in advance,
Lerbert

Comment: what data type is `price`? looks like a monetary value.

Comment: data type for price is decimal(20,2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to compare the prices you use LAG to look into the previous record.

```
select *
from
(
  select 
    ticker, 
    date, 
    price, 
    lag(price) over (partition by ticker order by date) as price_before
  from prices
) both_prices
where price > price_before * 1.5 or price < price_before * 0.5;
```

You can do this regularly in a batch of course. I don't know if it is also possible to cover this in a trigger, however.

Comment: might be worth noting that `LAG` is only available with 2012+

Comment: Than you for your answer I will try this out later today. I use SQL Server 2014 (express) so I think lag will be available then. Triggering will not be necessary, a weekly check with a batch should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

`LAG` would be the way to go for this problem as you're using 2014.

I'd written a CTE that would do this comparison, so I'll post it anyhow:

```
CREATE TABLE #StocksTable
    (
      [Ticker] VARCHAR(5) ,
      [Date] DATETIME ,
      [Price] DECIMAL(20, 2)
    );

INSERT  INTO #StocksTable
        ( [Ticker], [Date], [Price] )
VALUES  ( 'AMEAS', '2010-01-03 00:00:00', 11.20 ),
        ( 'AMEAS', '2010-01-02 00:00:00', 11.00 ),
        ( 'AMEAS', '2010-01-01 00:00:00', 10.00 ),
        ( 'KNEVB', '2010-01-03 00:00:00', 5.00 ),
        ( 'KNEVB', '2010-01-02 00:00:00', 3.50 ),
        ( 'KNEVB', '2010-01-01 00:00:00', 3.50 );

SELECT  * ,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY Ticker, [Date] ) rn
INTO    #StockProcessing
FROM    #StocksTable

;WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   * ,
                        CONVERT(DECIMAL(20, 2), 0) AS Diff
               FROM     #StockProcessing
               WHERE    rn = 1
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   sp.* ,
                        CASE WHEN sp.Ticker != cte.Ticker
                             THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(20, 2), 0)
                             ELSE CONVERT(DECIMAL(20, 2), sp.Price - cte.Price)
                        END AS Diff
               FROM     #StockProcessing sp
                        INNER JOIN cte ON sp.rn = cte.rn + 1
             )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    cte

DROP TABLE #StocksTable
DROP TABLE #StockProcessing
```

This simply compares the value from the previous day per `Ticker` and logs it in a new column for you. You can then use the values in that column as your indicators.

Comment: Thank you it's great to learn alternative solutions even though I will use the lag in this case.